# need quiet refrigerator for living room

Tags: kitchens, refrigerator, noise

We have an open-plan living room / kitchen. We installed IKEA furniture in the kitchen (Metod / Bobdyn). We have to choose a built-in fridge / freezer. For this IKEA kitchen one can only install
54cm * 54cm (width * depth) freezers.

Our biggest concern is noise.

We already tried Whirlpool ART9811 SF, and that was disappointingly noisy. It was advertised as 35dB, but when the compressor was on maximum level (after loading lots of stuff into) it was audible in the whole house for hours. Even when the compressor was off, there was a loud sloshing sound for hours. In the living room it was simply annoying. Fortunately we could send it back to the shop. It was not installed in the cabinet, but was leveled.

Then we tried AEG SCE618E5TS. It was advertised as 36dB, but was a LOT quieter than the Whirlpool. Still the no-frost fan was too noisy. We bought it with the option to send back...

Now I would really want to find an acceptable one.

The ideal one would be a SILENT fridge / freeze with ~200l fridge and ~70l freeze compartment. For me silent means that I can read a book on the sofa 5m away from the fridge without noticing that it is on.

How can I choose such a fridge?

What kind of compressor / fan / etc should I search for?

Are there recommended manufacturers for silent fridges maybe?

Will the IKEA cabinet absorb noise significantly? I checked the documentation, and there must be a sizable opening at the bottom and the top of the cabinet for air circulation, I am worried that noise will leak through there and there will be no real noise reduction.

Is no-frost technology neccessarily noisy? As far as I understood no-frost means a fan in the freeze section which circulates air. To me it seems easy to manufacture an almost noiseless fan (compared to manufacture a silent compressor), but maybe that's not the case?

Are fridges without freeze section significantly quieter? We started thinking on buying a fridge without freezer for the living room - kitchen, and put a freezer into the basement. Is it a good idea?

Should we look for stand alone fridges instead of the built in? A stand alone one would not look as good as a built in, but if that is the price for low noise than we would pay it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: FYI as I have tried similar things, any cabinet you use, will heat up fridge and make it louder.

Comment: If you happen to have a home stereo system, take a close look a the speakers. You'll note that they are made of cones which vibrate based on the signal sent to them _and reverberate inside a wooden box_. The box is integral to the amplification of the sound. You're putting something that's going to make _some_ noise into a speaker box and expecting this to suddenly be quiet. You'd have to foam pad the fridge surround to absorb the noise, but still allow for air flow if you are to have a hope of quieting the fridge.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you might be able to achieve that would be with a split refrigerator (compressor located elsewhere, preferably outdoors), and that's a very expensive custom deal. Quite normal for "walk-in refrigerators" seldom seen in a house-scale application.

There's the Peltier junction option, but it's laughably inefficient and will do a great job heating your house whether you want it to or not. "No moving parts - solid state" but truly laughably inefficient, and generally not available in a normal size fridge anyway.

Comment: Peltier or split refrigerator is obviously not an option for us. I don't want a noiseless fridge. I want one which is at least as quiet as the old (~20 years old) Snaige stand alone fridge we are replacing. That fridge was not noticeable to me 5m away.

Comment: That probably has something to do with "being used to its noises and ignoring them" as well as any objective measurement of noise level. I can hear my fridge running more than 5m away, but I can also sleep through my fridge running quite easily. It certainly makes audible noises of various sorts - I'm just used to them, so they are not **noticeable**. A different fridge would make different noises. Most appliance ratings use a deceptive weighting for noise level (long averaging time, so if it makes loud noises but only a little bit of the time, it still gets a low number...)